# p5.js ReferenceError: keyDown is not defined

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Created this simple code that should move a rect in `p5.js`. I get the error `ReferenceError: keyDown is not defined`.  What's wrong? Do I have to install any other libraries or is it a syntax error?

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
}
 
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

function draw() {
    if (keyDown(68)) // d
    {
        x += 3
    }
    if (keyDown(65)) // a 
    {
        x -= 3
    }
    if (keyDown(87)) 
    {
        y -= 3
    }
    if (keyDown(83)) 
    {
        y += 3
    }

    background(220)
    rect(x, y, 30, 50);
           
}
```

Comment: It's not really a "syntax error", it's just the wrong function name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error. The correct way to check for a keypress is `KeyIsDown(keycode)`:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
}
 
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

function draw() {
    if (keyIsDown(68)) // d
    {
        x += 3
    }
    if (keyIsDown(65)) // a 
    {
        x -= 3
    }
    if (keyIsDown(87)) 
    {
        y -= 3
    }
    if (keyIsDown(83)) 
    {
        y += 3
    }

    background(220)
    rect(x, y, 30, 50);
           
}
```

Comment: Works. Where can I check some docs?

Comment: Here: https://p5js.org/reference/. You can see info about every `p5.js` function.